# Triggering taskbar button flash from batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, taskbar

Is it possible to trigger Windows' "flash the task bar button X times or until the window comes to the foreground" behavior from a batch file?  I'm trying to call the user's attention to a long-running script upon completion.

Using an external program to trigger the flashing is fine, as long as it doesn't require an install (i.e. the executable can be bundled with my scripts).

**Update**

Here's what I ended up with (a minimalist port of Andreas' Delphi code).  I've compiled it under MinGW at it appears to be dependent only on KERNEL32.DLL and USER32.DLL, so should be highly portable.

Flashes three times, then stays highlighted until brought to the foreground.

```c
#define WINVER 0x501
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x501

#include <windows.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FLASHWINFO info = { sizeof(info), GetConsoleWindow(), FLASHW_TIMERNOFG | FLASHW_TRAY, 3, 0 };

    FlashWindowEx(&info);
}
```

Comment: Such an interesting question, and only three views in 45 minutes?!

Comment: ...and only 15 views in 24 hours. I don't get it...

Comment: Yes, `GetConsoleWindow` is much better than `FindWindow` and a unique caption. Don't know why I didn't do that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very easy to do using a very simple external *.exe. It simply has to call the [`FlashWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679347(VS.85).aspx) function of the Windows API.

This is a sample Delphi console application:

```pascal
program flashwnd;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

var
  OldTitle, UniqueTitle: string;
  h: HWND;
  c: cardinal;
  fwi: TFlashWInfo;

begin

  try
    h := GetConsoleWindow();

    c := 10;
    if ParamCount = 1 then
      c := StrToInt(ParamStr(1));

    FillChar(fwi, sizeof(fwi), 0);
    fwi.cbSize := sizeof(fwi);
    fwi.hwnd := h;
    fwi.dwFlags := FLASHW_ALL;
    fwi.uCount := c;
    fwi.dwTimeout := 0;
    FlashWindowEx(fwi);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Simply call it like

```
flashwnd
```

to flash the current console window ten times. Call

```
flashwnd 27
```

to flash the window 27 times.

Comment: I suspected something like this would be the case, but am hopeless at Windows APIs!  I'll see if I can get this working.

Comment: Finally got it working in MinGW (as I have no Delphi compiler handy).  Thanks!

Comment: hi Ben, any chance you have the compiled version of this utility? thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/joeyespo/console-flash ("Releases" have pre-compiled binary)