# How I can compile this C++ code that fails with "'::main' must return 'int'"?

Tags: c++

I have tried to find a solution that make batch file start flashing on taskbar and only good solution was [this post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560018/triggering-taskbar-button-flash-from-batch-file).

But I can't compile the code with WinGW or anything else to EXE, only getting this error:

```
hello.cpp:6:32: error: '::main' must return 'int'
```

Right now, I'm using [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) to compile code, because it's bit better...

Can somebody give me code that actually works or even better compile it to EXE already?

P.S. Even more better if somebody could [compile this Delphi code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560018/triggering-taskbar-button-flash-from-batch-file/3560079#3560079), because I can't find any software that's free.

EDIT: I just go hell with it and downloaded Delphi trial and complied the delphi code and it worked! Sorry guys for bugging you unnecessarily :/ You can close this.

Comment: About your P.S., try [`Lazarus`](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/). It's free.

Answer (score 7):

It's actually `int main()`, and the end must return an integer (so make the last line above "}" `return 0;` (indicates a successful run, anything non-zero is otherwise).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int errors;

int main(arg stuff) {
    std::cout << "C++!";

    if (errors > 0)
         return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There never was `void main`.

Comment: If you leave out the `return`, the default is to `return 0;` anyway.

Comment: http://vineetgupta22.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/int-main-vs-void-main-vs-int-main-void-vs-main/